# How do you get all web requests with Nightmare.js?

Tags: javascript

With the old version of Nightmare.JS (<1.7.0) it seemed like you could easily get what resources a URL fetches. However, with the switch to electron, I can't figure out what to do to get all the requests.

Answer (score -1):

DEBUG=nightmare:logs node [your-script-name] [arguments(if any)]